# Laravel 5.2: how to pass data to controller using ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

Hi I am new to Laravel and I am trying to pass some data to controller using an ajax call.

**Route**

```
Route::post('/category', 'FrontendController@category');
```

**Controller**

```
 public function category(Request $request){

     $data = $request->all();
 }
```

**Ajax call**

```
 var name= 'John';

        $.ajax({
            method: 'post',
            url: '{{url("/category")}}', 
            data: {'name' : name}, 
            success: function(response){ 
                console.log(response);

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
                console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Using the code above I gef following error: 
**MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218**

Comment: What url are you hitting? Go to network tab and see if there's any issue.

Comment: try just  url: '/category'

Comment: Also, add csrf token to your data params, while performing ajax request.

Comment: Hi, Gaurav I changed the url and put csrf token. Now I get this error:405 (Method Not Allowed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

> Step 1: Create BASE_URL in constructor of Controller

```
public function __construct() {
   if (!defined('BASE_URL')) define('BASE_URL', url('/') . '/');
}
```

> Step 2: Define Route

```
Route::post('category', 'CategoryController@postCategory');
```

> Step 3: Add "BASE_URL" to HTML and implement that in Script.

```
<script>
    var APP = APP || {};
    APP.baseUrl = "{{ BASE_URL }}";

    window.Laravel = <?php echo json_encode([
        'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
    ]); ?>
</script>
```

then,

```
$(function(){
    var loadMoreRequest = null;

    $('#formSubmit').on('click', function(){
        if (loadMoreRequest !== null) {
           return;
        }

        loadMoreRequest = $.ajax({
           url: APP.baseUrl + '/category',
           data: {'_token': window.Laravel.csrfToken},
           type: 'POST',
           asyn: false,
           success: function (data) {
               console.log('Yay!')

               loadMoreRequest = null;
           },
           error: function() {
               loadMoreRequest = null;
           }
        });
    });
});
```

See, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the `method: 'post'` to `type: 'post'`, it will start working

and for adding the csrf token with every ajax request follow this [Laravel CSRF Token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token)

Add this meta tag in your `head` section

`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`

and then add this in your javascript section

```
<script>
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
</script>
```